Python can't import installed module
I'm trying to run an legacy app with flask. Among all errors, i've encountered a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.ext' "
So, as with others ModuleNotFoundError, i installed the 'wtforms' module with 'python3 -m pip install wtf' but did not worked.
I've also tried: 'flask_wtf', 'wtforms.ext', 'WTForms', 'flask-wtf', 'Flask-WTF', 'wtf' and 'wtf --use-pep517'. None of them work

Does anyone got a hint?
Thanks

The wtforms.ext module you’re trying to import has been deprecated (2.3.1 wtform changelogs) in recent versions of WTForms.
Solution:
E.g. if using wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy (for example, oyu may be using something else), replace is with WTForms-Alchemy:
python3 -m pip install WTForms-Alchemy

Fix imports:
# Old import
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

# New import
from wtforms_alchemy import QuerySelectField

Review the linked documentation to find any specific replacements you might have in your code or setup.
